# In Flask Web application, how to display json file data with search box filter?

Tags: json, flask, web-applications, python-requests

Can someone please help me ? I want to display the data like truckid , name etc in the table to user on webpage  , if he searches by truck id in the search box..

The HTML code for the search box is :

```
<form method="GET">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mb-2 mb-md-0">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter truck-id">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Search</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Sample Json File is :

{

```
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 6,
"Fleet": [{
        "Truck": {
            "id": "12345GHJ",
            "name": "OilTank"
        },
        "driver": "Sarah driverlady",
        "summary": "Deliver oil to businesses in town abcd",
        "description": "Deliver oil to businesses in town abcd drive from office to this town before 01 January and return before 10 January. More detailed notes about the job are added here",
        "DateJobSubmitted": "2020-07-13T18:15:00Z"
    },
    {
        "Truck": {
            "id": "789456GGY",
            "name": "Frozen Food"
        },
        "driver": "Mike Andrews",
        "summary": "Deliver frozen food to businesses in town abcd",
        "description": "Deliver oil to businesses in town abcd drive from office to this town before 01 January and return before 10 January. More detailed notes about the job are added here",
        "DateJobSubmitted": "2020-07-13T18:15:00Z"
    }
]
```

}

```
The py file code for this part is :

with open('samplefile.json', 'r') as m : 
    data = json.load(m) 

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/truck_id",methods=["GET","POST"])
def truck_id():
    return render_template('truck_id.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML file, give a 'name' to the input tag.
In the python file, under truck_id() fetch the information using request command.
The check if the text is inside the son file by parsing it. If it is there send a status along with render_template.

Here is an example, make changes accordingly:

HTML File:

```
<form method="GET">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mb-2 mb-md-0">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter truck-id" name = 'truck_id'>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Search</button>
            </div>
          </div>
</form>

{% if status == "found" %}
<p>The items is found </p>
{% endif %}
{% if status == "not found" %}
<p>The items is not found </p>
{% endif %}
```

Python File:

```
with open('samplefile.json', 'r') as m : 
data = json.load(m) 

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/truck_id",methods=["GET","POST"])
def truck_id():
    status = ""
    details = request.form
    truck_id = details['truck_id']
    if truck_id in json:
       //do the JSON parsing here
       if found:
          status = "found"
       else:
          status = "not found"
    return render_template('truck_id.html',status = status)
```

So, this way you can check! Hereby attaching my [GitHub](https://github.com/saro-mano/FlaskCRUD.git) link where I have performed basic CRUD operations.